# How to solve GMP C++ Installation, can not find ../libgmp.la problem on MAC OS X

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, gnu, gmp

I have downloaded GMP 6.2.1 from the link supplied from the website to my macos Big Sur, unzipped it. I runned the configure script and

```
make check 
make install
```

then realized I should have added --enable-cxx to `./configure --enable-cxx`. I did that and rerun `make check`.
Error I've got is

```
libtool: warning: '-no-install' is ignored for broadwell-apple-darwin20.5.0
libtool: warning: assuming '-no-fast-install' instead
libtool:   error: cannot find the library '../libgmp.la' or unhandled argument' ../libgmp.la'
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Any reason you cannot use brew or macports to install gmp?

Comment: Where did you find instructions to go directly from configure to check?

Comment: I tried to use brew but it said gmp is already installed and I don't know how to fully uninstall gmp.

Comment: This is the instruction I followed https://gmplib.org/manual/Installing-GMP but I now realize that I did ```make``` before ```make check``` but the second time around I didn't (This explains why gmp is working for C but not for C++). At the moment I am trying again with ```make``` before ```make check```

Comment: If you have installed GMP with `brew` previously, it suffices to adapt your compiler invocation to look for include files in `/opt/homebrew/include`, and look for libraries in `/opt/homebrew/lib`. How to do that exactly depends on how your project is set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the instructions from https://gmplib.org/manual/Installing-GMP correctly the first time but the second time I didn't run `make` before `make check`. Following the manual **exactly** solved my problem.